# SSL on Apache2 with WSGI

Tags: ssl, apache2, wsgi

I am trying to set up SSL on a Django site I maintain and having a bit of trouble setting up my VirtualHost with SSL. I followed the instructions [here](http://beeznest.wordpress.com/2008/04/25/how-to-configure-https-on-apache-2/) but every time I try to restart apache, it tells me it cannot restart because of multiple virtualhosts usign the same wsgi config:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 reload
Syntax error on line 33 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/www.mydomain.com:
Name duplicates previous WSGI daemon definition.
...fail!
```

I understand what is happening, just not how to fix it. Any suggestions are appreciated, thanks! Here is what my VirutalHosts file looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin my@email.com
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /sites/mydomain

    # WSGI Settings
    WSGIScriptAlias / /sites/mydomain/wsgi_handler.py
    WSGIDaemonProcess mydomain user=myuser group=mygroup processes=1 threads=1
    WSGIProcessGroup mydomain

    # Static Directories
    Alias /static /sites/mydomain/static/
    <Location "/static">
            SetHandler None
    </Location>

    Alias /img /sites/mydomain/img/
    <Location "/img">
            SetHandler None
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin my@email.com
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /sites/mydomain

    # WSGI Settings
    WSGIScriptAlias / /sites/mydomain/wsgi_handler.py
    WSGIDaemonProcess mydomain user=myuser group=mygroup processes=1 threads=1
    WSGIProcessGroup mydomain

    # Static Directories
    Alias /static /sites/mydomain/static/
    <Location "/static">
            SetHandler None
    </Location>

    Alias /img /sites/mydomain/img/
    <Location "/img">
            SetHandler None
    </Location>

    # SSL Stuff
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/crt/vhost1.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/key/vhost1.key
    <Location />
            SSLRequireSSL On
            SSLVerifyClient optional
            SSLVerifyDepth 1
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars +StrictRequire
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Remove the line:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess mydomain user=myuser group=mygroup processes=1 threads=1
```

from the VirtualHost for 443. The WSGIProcessGroup for mydomain in that VirtualHost is able to reach across to the WSGIDaemonProcess definition in 80.

In other words, as the error message tries to suggest, the name for the WSGIDaemonProcess, ie., 'mydomain', must be unique for the whole Apache server.

Referring across VirtualHosts as indicated means both HTTP and HTTPS variants of site will still run in same daemon process group/interpreter.

Answer (score 12):

Posting in hopes it will help another...

I encountered this error because a virtual host file had been symlinked twice in the sites-enabled directory.

Comment: Silly me, I pasted the same conf file for backup purposes inside the sites-enabled folder. Thanks!